# Naming columns with alter table in MySQL using variables

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to name a column in a table using variables? For example lets say I want to create a table with columns named col1, col2, col3 using a while loop where the integer in the column name equals the current position in the loop.
What should I replace the dots with below?

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD ... INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: Maybe, but you would NEVER want to do this.

Comment: Well, for starters see normalization

Answer (score 0):

```
$numberOfColumnsRequired = $_POST['user_requested_tables'];
$i = 1;
while ($i < $numberOfColumnsRequired && $i <= 30) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE table1 ADD `col{$i}` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL");
    $i++;
}
```

Something like this will accomplish the task... However this opens the door to a lot of potentially nasty things to happen.

Why do you need this? What are you trying to do? Id rather propose a better solution.

Edit: added a maximum number of columns that can be added.

Comment: I want to create a setup where you create a table from a webpage by typing the number of columns the table should consist of in a textbox. The names are then given by the number you've entered. I want it to be used in a stored procedure. More over I'm using VB.NET :)

Comment: Well I still wouldnt recommend processes like this, theyre really more control than end users traditionally need. If you must, the code above will do what you asked. I would recommend putting a hard limit on the number of columns that can be added. Also use a <select> list instead of a text box.

Comment: I'll add the limit to the textbox so that no more than ten columns can be added this way. I still want to use this and preferrably inside the stored procedure so that all queris are handled from there. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Im sorry, I really dont work with stored procedures much. In my understanding you would need to have your loop within the prepared statement and pass it the number of requested columns. Basically the same thing i have written above but in MySQL. Im sorry I dont know the exact syntax for it.